# Updating openssl on Windows 2003 Server - "openssl version" doesn't show new version

Tags: windows, ssl

I want to update **OpenSSL** on a **Windows Server 2003**. After installing it to C:\OpenSSL-Win32 and copy the OpenSSL DLLs to the Windows System Directory everything seems fine. I downloaded the executable from [this site](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Here is my problem: When I type "**openssl version**" I get the message:

> " 'openssl' is not recognized as an internal  or external command,
>   operable program or batch file."

I set the environment variables to the openssl.exe in C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin but I still get the message quoted above. Please give me a hint on how to update openssl properly. If it's a documentation I missed to read please post it. Help is very appreciated :)

Comment: What environment variables did you set, and what did you set them to exactly?

Comment: User variables for [User]

Variable name: OPENSSL_CONF
Variable value: C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe
                                                                System variables                                                              
Variable name: OPENSSL_CONF
Variable value:C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe

Comment: For you to be able to run `openssl` without the current directory being `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin`, you will need to add `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin` to the system's `PATH` environment variable.